# Code in Documentation not colored

Tags: discussion, documentation

I already edit a post in Documentation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/primefaces/1027/getting-started-with-primefaces/27721/input-text-slider-in-primefaces#t=201701260659152718976 and i notice that the old code is colored and the new one is not, why this :

[image: codes documentation]

***Do you think because it is already waiting to be validated, or why exactly ?***

**Edit**

***I don't think so, my post is already validated but it still not grey and black.***

Answer (score 3):

The other posts mark up the content explicitly. If you look at their source you'll find they include:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
```

before each codeblock.

Comment: I saw that as well, but I can't really find whether that's supposed to work like that. When does the documentation site add language hints?

Comment: @CodeCaster: when the associated tag has a highlighting language configured. The Python tag has 'python' configured, for example, so the Python documentation also uses that. Primafaces explicitly sets the highlighter to *none*, probably because you usually tag such questions with Java (which does have one), and questions usually mix Java and XML blocks.

Comment: yes it work now, thank you, but is that required every time?

Comment: @YCF_L: yes; the Primafaces tag explicitly sets the highlighter to *none*, because posts about the subject typically mix XML and Java, so any default would be wrong for half the codeblocks.